# SafeAreaView doesn't working in react native version 0.54.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, iphone-x

I read that facebook introduce new API [**SafeAreaView**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/983b05441d3d23809b924de2e4bf96a55c47428duse) for iPhone X. and I use the react native latest version 0.54.0, You can see my below code. but SafeAreaView doesn't work for iPhone X device.

**Code :**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={[globalStyle.fontRegularLarge , styles.welcome]}>
          React Native Demo App
        </Text>

        <View style={{position: 'absolute' , height: 150 , bottom: 0 , width: '100%'}}>
          <Text style={[globalStyle.fontRegular , styles.welcome]}>
            © 2018 Kirit Modi, PTE. LTD. - Proprietary & Confidential
          </Text>

          <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.getStartBtn}>
            <Text style={[globalStyle.fontRegular , {color: 'white'}]}>
              Get Start
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

**iPhoneX and iPhone 6s**

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the attached images, it seems that `SafeAreaView` is working perfectly.

The purpose of `SafeAreaView` is to ensure your application displays correctly on the iPhoneX by avoiding/adjusting the content that interacts with the sensor cluster ("the notch") or the home activity indicator("bar").

I suggest you to take the advantage of full screen of iPhone X instead of running the app in 'Legacy Mode'. For more details on this one check this [article](https://blog.callstack.io/react-native-meets-iphonex-a0f5034f7a41)

[image]